# "apt install <name>.deb" not correctly installing Nvidia driver in the deb package

Tags: debian, apt, nvidia, dpkg, deb

EDIT solution: The problem was that I thought the package installs the driver but it was not the case (more about it in the accepted answer). When installing Nvidia driver I suggest going with .run file from archive [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/) - if you need specific version, which was my case so I could not just autoinstall. The .deb package was not working for me.

EDIT2: I tried to install Cuda just now and failed. I've read there might be issues when using ".run" file, so I don't know if that is the way to go anymore.

I have **Debian 10 (Buster)** and I'm trying to install [Nvidia driver 460.91](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/178339/en-us). I downloaded it and tried to install as root by executing:

```
apt install ./<name>.deb
```

What I get is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA0vd.png

and the driver is not installed.

**Why the Nvidia driver is not installed when it is claiming that the package is? Also the first run was extremely fast so it could not possibly install the driver.**

I tried among other things running

```
sudo dpkg -i <name>.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

but got same result. For some reason it seems that the package is installed however the driver is not.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: @Kusalananda Will avoid in the future. Seemed to me like a best way but now I realize it can be useful to copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not installing the package because the package is already installed:

> ```
> nvidia-driver-local-repo-debian10-460.91.03 is already the newest version (1.0-1).
> ```

This package ships all the packages needed, but doesn’t install them; to do that, you need to run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver
```

Comment: I don't understand, when I check if the driver is present (by executing nvidia-smi in terminal) it tells me "command not found" so I think the driver is not installed. EDIT: In the first run it was different but it definitely did not install the driver, it was like 0.5s.

Comment: I take it you think you’re installing the driver, but the package you’ve downloaded installs a repository containing the driver; it doesn’t install the driver itself. What instructions are you following?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did try to "apt update" but I get some error in it: https://i.imgur.com/VQ0lcNg.png

Comment: I tried to "apt remove nvidia..." so I can try to install the configuration package again but after it I still see "nvidia-driver..." in "dpkg --list". When I tried to "dpkg --remove nvidia..." it fails on 
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
.

Comment: So after a while I decided to find a different way, found archive https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/linux-amd64-display-archive/ with .run files (I understand similar to .exe on Win containing the instalation script), picked the one https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/177149/en-us I needed and the installation seemed to work, at least now i see report when i type "nvidia-smi".

Comment: The issue with those `*.run` files is that they aren't tailored for the debian environment and not 'packaged'.  It may not be a problem for you, but you may find un-installing or upgrading that driver to be difficult: something the repository and `apt install` will help you with.  There could also be conflicts with other libraries on your system or missing dependencies, but maybe not.